# Slicing Dataframe with elements as lists

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has list as elements and I want to have more efficient way to check for some conditions.

My dataframe looks like this

```
col_a   col_b
0   100 [1, 2, 3]
1   200 [2, 1]
2   300 [3]
```

I want to get only those rows which have 1 in col_b.

I have tried the naive way
temp_list=list()

```
for i in range(len(df1.index)):    
    if 1 in df1.iloc[i,1]:
        temp_list.append(df1.iloc[i,0])
```

This takes a lot of time for big dataframes like this. How could I make the search more efficient for dataframes like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can a list comprehension to check if `1` is present in a given list, and use the result to perform [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) on the dataframe:

```
df.loc[[1 in i for i in df.col_B ],:]

    col_a      col_B
0    100  [1, 2, 3]
1    200     [2, 1]
```

---

Here's another approach using `sets`:

```
df[df.col_B.ne(df.col_B.map(set).sub({1}).map(list))]

   col_a      col_B
0    100  [1, 2, 3]
1    200     [2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with list comprehension and loc for seelct column `col_a`:

```
a = df1.loc[[1 in x for x in df1['col_b']], 'col_a'].tolist()
print (a)
[100, 200]
```

If need select first column:

```
a = df1.iloc[[1 in x for x in df1['col_b']], 0].tolist()
print (a)
[100, 200]
```

If need all rows:

```
df2 = df1[[1 in x for x in df1['col_b']]]
print (df2)
   col_a      col_b
0    100  [1, 2, 3]
1    200     [2, 1]
```

Another solution with `set`s and `isdisjoint`:

```
df2 = df1[~df1['col_b'].map(set({1}).isdisjoint)]
print (df2)
   col_a      col_b
0    100  [1, 2, 3]
1    200     [2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.col_b.apply(lambda x: 1 in x)]
```

Results in:

```
col_a   col_b
0   100 [1, 2, 3]
1   200 [2, 1]
```

Comment: Great solution !

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with this approach:

```
df['col_b'] = df.apply(lambda x: eval(x['col_b']), axis = 1)  
s=df['col_b']
d = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
df = pd.concat([df, d], axis=1); 
print(df)
print('...')
print(df[1.0])
```

---

That gave me the indices like this at the end (column with the name `1.0` as number):

```
   id  col_a      col_b  1.0  2.0  3.0
0   1    100  (1, 2, 3)    1    1    1
1   2    200     (1, 2)    1    1    0
2   3    300          3    0    0    1
...
0    1
1    1
2    0
Name: 1.0, dtype: uint8
```

To printout the result:

```
df.loc[df[1.0]==1, ['id', 'col_a', 'col_b']]
```